# Can't avoid manual cast

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2.6

Retrofit 2.6.

```
 @GET("/event")
    suspend fun getEvents(@Query("orgn") base: Int, @Query("event") quote: Int): Response<List<Event>>
```

In service:

```
import retrofit2.Response

 suspend fun getEvents(
            orgn: Int,
            event: Int,
            isCustomtHandle: Boolean = false
        ): Response<*> {
           return waitressCallRestClient.getEvents(orgn, event)
        }
```

and in my ViewModel:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope

 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val response = TransportService.getEvents(100, 200)
            if (response.isSuccessful) { 
                val eventList: List<Event> = response.body() as List<Event>
```

As you can see I must cast to `List<Event>`
Is it possible to avoid manual cast?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Any** like this way

```
@GET("/event")
suspend fun getEvents(@Query("orgn") base: Int, @Query("event") quote: Int): Response<List<Any>>
```

then

```
val eventList: List<Any> = response.body()
```

Comment: I get compile error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Any? but List<Any> was expected